# Create a file inside a new folder in sdcard

Tags: android, file, path, android-sdcard, createfile

I was trying to create a new file and a new folder inside my sdcard directory, but without any type of progress. I have tried differents code but nobody works. This is my last code that I have tried:

```
package dev.lordwalrus.alita;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
            if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                newFolder.mkdir();
            }

            File file = new File(newFolder, "MyTest" + ".txt");
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I have added in my android manifest permission to write and read external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I am using android min sdk version 21.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Where asking permissions to user?

Comment: Yep, I didn't know that I have to ask permission to user

Answer (score 0):

For Android 6.0+ you should ask for permission manually. Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for more information. Declaring itself doesn't guarantee you can write anything to external storage. Also, starting from Android 10, you should also specify FileProvider. Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)

Comment: Glad it helped. You can mark this answer and the correct one and upvote :) Thanks